# Docusign composite template not being received by recipients but is shown on DS inbox/sent

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm following the recipe that can be found here:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-adding-document-template#run-the-example

But I found that despite the envelope is shown as sent on the docusign inbox, the recipients won't receive it, here's the code...

```
const tabs = getTabsMethodWorkingForStandaloneTemplates({
    name: "name",
    email: "name@email.com"
});
// Create a signer recipient for the signer role of the server template
let signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
    email: args.signerEmail,
    name: args.signerName,
    roleName: "signer",
    recipientId: "1",
    // Adding clientUserId transforms the template recipient
    // into an embedded recipient:
    clientUserId: args.signerClientId,
    tabs
});

// Recipients object:
let recipientsServerTemplate = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
    signers: [signer1],
});

// create a composite template for the Server Template
let compTemplate1 = docusign.CompositeTemplate.constructFromObject({
    compositeTemplateId: "1",
    serverTemplates: [
        docusign.ServerTemplate.constructFromObject({
            sequence: 1,
            templateId: args.templateId
        })
    ],
    // Add the roles via an inlineTemplate
    inlineTemplates: [
        docusign.InlineTemplate.constructFromObject({
            sequence: 1,
            recipients: recipientsServerTemplate
        })
    ]
});



//const compTemplate2 = getCompositeTemplateFromHTML(args);

const eventNotification = new docusign.EventNotification();
eventNotification.url = 'http://pj.pagekite.me';
eventNotification.includeDocuments = true;
eventNotification.loggingEnabled = true;
eventNotification.envelopeEvents = getEnvelopeEvents();

// create the envelope definition
let env = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition.constructFromObject({
    status: "sent",
    compositeTemplates: [
        compTemplate1,
    //  compTemplate2
    ],
    eventNotification
});

try {
    // Step 2. call Envelopes::create API method
    // Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
    let results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(
        args.accountId,
        {envelopeDefinition: env}
    );

    let envelopeId = results.envelopeId;
    console.log(`Envelope was created. EnvelopeId ${envelopeId}`);
} catch (e) {
    debugger
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `clientUserId` in there. That means embedded signing. Remove that and an email will be sent for remote signing. These two are mutual exclusive. Can't have them both.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!